# Is there a spark configuration to automatically detach a notebook from the cluster after a certain idle threshold?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

Databricks states under its documentation ([link](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-manage.html)) that the default threshold to automatically detach a notebook from a cluster is 24 hours.

Looking at the spark documentation ([link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)), I am not able to see the configuration to change this default.

Is there a spark configuration to change the default idle threshold to automatically detach a notebook?

Comment: You can post this question in [MS Q&A  Ask a question - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/ask.html)  with tag `Pyspark`, so it is picked up by MS Product Group for response